# Address Resolution Protocol (ARP) & RARP in netwrokig

Tags: networking, arp

ARP and RARP are the main Protocol uses in Link Layer. To do the ARP request, a device requires IP and MAC address pair for broadcasting. So my question is ARP doing the mapping the IP to MAC by referring the data
and operates using the LAN.

So RARP is the reverse algorithm of that like mapping logical address to physical address in caches in Computer Systems.

I hope a good answer from the community.

Comment: "_So RARP is the reverse algorithm of that like mapping logical address to physical address in caches in Computer Systems._" No, not at all. RARP has been deprecated for decades, first by BOOTP, then DHCP. RARP was used for a computer to find its own IP address.

Comment: Thanks @RonManupin. I think I got confuse about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are dozens of protocols that use the data-link layer the same way ARP does, including IPv4, IPv6, etc. See *[IEEE 802 Numbers](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ieee-802-numbers/ieee-802-numbers.xhtml)* for a list of protocols that use the data-link layer.

For protocols in the data-link layer, there are/were many. For example, token ring, ARCNET, FDDI, frame relay, HDLC, ATM, PPP, etc. Ethernet used to be the king, but Wi-Fi has dethroned it since there are more devices shipping with Wi-Fi interfaces than devices with ethernet interfaces.